# A (probably very simple) question on injective objects.

Tags: category-theory

Do they form a category? Let me be more specific:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category andd denote by $I(\mathcal{C})$ the collection of injective objects in $\mathcal{C}$ (with respect to monomorphisms). Can we make $I(\mathcal{C})$ into a category? What are the morphisms? And is this (potential) category studied somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Any sub-collection of the objects of category can be made into a sub-category (usually in several ways). In particular as a full sub-category (i.e. when we take all morphisms between those objects in the sub-collection) or as a discrete sub-category (i.e. when we take only identity morphisms).